# Angularjs form imposible to validate

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, validation

I am facing a peculiar issue with Angularjs 1.3.2

I am trying to setup a form with angular validation, which I did many times before. Only this time there is no way to make my inputs valid.

This is what my html looks like:

```html
<form name="user.form">
  <input name="email" class="form-control" type="text" ng-model="user.email" required>
</form>
```

My controller (this is from a ng-view, since I am using angularjs routes):

```js
var mod = angular.module("userEdit", [ "ngRoute" ]);
mod.controller('UserEditCtrl', function ($scope)
{
   ...
   $scope.user = { email : "" };
   ...
});
```

And this is the result that I get in Google Chrome's elements console, with empty input :

```html
<input name="email" class="form-control ng-pristine ng-untouched ng-invalid ng-invalid-required" type="text" ng-model="user.email" required="">
```

With non empty input :

```
<input name="email" class="form-control ng-invalid ng-dirty ng-valid-parse ng-valid-required ng-touched" type="text" ng-model="user.email" required="">
```

There must be something I do wrong but I can't figure out what.

Comment: Can't reproduce... Check the [**fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/tivie/zb8mwfyv/). Well, it does not work exactly as expected, since as soon as you introduce some characters, it becomes valid but... that's not the problem you're having right?

Comment: @Tivie I tried in fiddle and it works. But not on my project.
Also I don't know where this 'ng-valid-parse' comes from.
It's crazy because the form cannot be more easy, but still it stays invalid no matter what.

Comment: I've tried in a different controller and a different form, same result. I think my angular is broken.

Comment: Also my `user.form.$error` is empty

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For those who may have the same mistake, for me it was simply a bad game with the prototype.
I had declared :

```
Object.prototype.removeAll = function()...
```

That didn't end up well for my app.
One should not play with prototypes without fully understanding them.